# Meaning of statistically significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

I'm a little confused with the meaning of a statistically significant result. Does statistically significant just mean it's a phenomenon worth exploring given that there is a high likelihood of seeing a value as extreme as the observed value? And we should do further tests to understand the phenomenon?

Comment: Click on the [statistical-significance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/statistical-significance/info) tag to see its description. It tells what statistical significance is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RichardHardy. The tag describes the methodology to determine if a desired statistic is statistical significant. What I'm wondering is whether determining if something is statistically significant means something.

Comment: It means that the p-value we found is below an arbitrary value (often 0.05)

Comment: Thanks @DemetriPananos I've read your answer on the question. So, what I can take away from it is that statistically significant is just having the evidence to evaluate what I want to do with the null hypothesis and nothing more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In frequentist statistics we regularly do hypothesis tests that yield a p-value. The p-value tells us the probability of observing data at least as extreme as the data we actually observed, if in fact the null hypothesis is true. If the p-value is smaller than a pre-determined level, then we say that we found a *"statistically significant"* result.

The mistake that many people make is placing the desire to find a "significant" result above almost anything else, when in fact there are other very important considerations. One way I like to explain this is by thinking about a hypothetic trial for a new drug that is designed to lower blood pressure. Let's imagine that we find the drug reduces blood pressure by 0.2mm HG and the p-value is 0.049, with a pre-chosen significance level of 0.05. So we have found a statistically significant result. However, 0.2mm HG is a very small effect size that clinicians would find to be completely meaningless. So statistical significance should always be considered alongside practical or clinical significance.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the answer. Correct me if I'm wrong, so a statistically significant result has no intrinsic meaning but only serves to tell us more about the null hypothesis?

Comment: @RenMizukiIsaDataScientist What is precisely is "intrinsic meaning in contrast to just "meaning"?

Comment: @Galen Sorry for making it more confusing. The question is: Other than telling us whether to reject/accept the null hypothesis, is there any other purpose?

Comment: From hypothesis testing more generally, you can obtain effect sizes that are sometimes meaningful. But the statistical significance part is just pertaining to the rejection of the null hypothesis.

Comment: Alright. Thanks @Galen! Appreciate the help